# Curl and etc. HTTP requests not working when I connected to vpn

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, http, curl

Please tell me how to solve next problem: Curl and etc. HTTP requests not working when I connected to vpn. I get a simple error - "could not resolve host". But when i disconnect from vpn everything works fine

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on Hetzner and Surfshark VPN.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sounds like you are configured to use a DNS server that is inaccessible when the VPN is engaged, though that is likely good, because it implies that you would be leaking DNS queries if it worked (they are not going through the VPN) potentially allowing the ISP to see the very information you are trying to hide from them. how do you have DNS configured?